# filter text field so it only supports integers and is not empty in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I am working with vue.js and I need that in a text field I can only enter integer values, in addition to not allowing the value of the quantity to be 0, and if the field is empty assign it the value 1. only and tried this not to allow decimals:

```
<input type="number" min="1" @keydown="filterKey"></input>

filterKey(e){
  const key = e.key;
  if (key === '.')
  return e.preventDefault();
}
```

but i dont know how to control the other filters, any ideas how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

try this:
script:

```
  data: () => ({
    num: 1
  }),
  methods: {
    filterKey(e) {
      const key = e.key;
      if (key === ".") return e.preventDefault();
    },
    change(e) {
      if (!this.num || parseInt(this.num, 0) === 0) this.num = 1;
      else this.num = parseInt(this.num, 0);
    }
  }
```

template:

```
<input type="number" v-model="num" @keydown="filterKey" @blur="change">
```